# I want to put Xubuntu 13.04 on an old laptop with Windows 98 on it, can someone tell me how to put Xubuntu on?

Tags: 13.04, windows, xubuntu

I am just doing this for fun so please don't give me some super long code to put in a terminal. I will post a picture once I get enough rep.

Comment: So you do want to keep 98?

Comment: @Mitch no I want to replace it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install Xubuntu, first you need to download the [32bit](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/) for your machine.  Once downloaded, you can either burn to DVD using [Imgburn](http://www.imgburn.com/), or create a bootable USB using [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) depending on what your machine can handle.  Once that is done, set the boot priority in the BIOS to boot from Either the DVD or USB.  Once booted, follow the screens below.

[image]

Click on Install Xubuntu.  If you want to see if everything is OK, before installing choose Try Xubuntu

[image]

[image]

Your option might say something like replace Windows 98, if not just choose erase Disk and Install

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]